# Get whole string from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a page that will allow me to select an item from a list pulled form a mysql Table

The code is below:

```
echo "<form action=\"\" method=\"post\">";

$sql="SELECT dgname FROM disguide";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
echo "<SELECT NAME=\"selectdgname\">";
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

$id=$row["dgname"];

  echo "<OPTION VALUE=$id>$id</option>";


}
echo "</select>";
echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Continue\">";
echo "</form>";

$selectdgname = $_POST['selectdgname'];

echo "<br><br><pre>";
echo $selectdgname;
echo "</pre><br><br>";


?>
```

The slect part works fine however when I want to post the data all I get is the first word.

How can i get the whole string?

Sample Output from MySQL

```
select dgname from disguide;
+----------------+
| dgname         |
+----------------+
| this is test 1 |
| this is test 2 |
| this is test 3 |
+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

My end result is to be able to use that string to call a query to fetch the whole doc.

Comment: You need quotes (`"`) around the value of an html option tag: `echo "<OPTION VALUE=\"$id\">$id</option>";`

Comment: That was it thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. Have fun!